# how to subtract the Euro Money from USD for a single self lookup object

Tags: multi-currency

I have an custom object which has self lookup . this object acts a money pool  from where everyone gets the money.

Lets say records A has created with 100k $ . 
Now records B  has created which a child of A with 50 K $  and record C has been created which is also a  child of A with 30K EURO. Now I have to subtract the amount from A and display the remaining amount

A Amount - 100 $
  ---  B Amount 50 $ (subtract from A)
 ---  C Amount  30 euro  (subtract from A)

who to calculate the remaining amount of A in $ . Thanks .

Comment: is the parent record always in USD? or could parent be in EUR and children in USD and the parent net value has to be in EUR?